# Get Grouped Property in Loop with Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have some `CartItems` which I have grouped by property `FleetID`.

```
var groupedCartItems = cart.CartItems.OrderBy(x => x.FleetID)
                           .GroupBy(x => x.FleetID);

foreach (var fleetItem in groupedCartItems)
{
    /////// var currentFleetID = fleetItem.GroupedFleetID;   ////////
    foreach(var itm in fleetItem)
    {

    }
}
```

In a loop of each group, how can I access the `FleetID` property that it is grouped by?

Comment: `fleetItem.Key`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your case, you are grouping based on a single column, so it can be accessed through the group key. which means `fleetItem.Key` will give you the key of the particular group in that iteration. if you want to access the same from inner loop means you can use `itm.FleetID`.

```
foreach (var fleetItem in groupedCartItems)
{
     var currentFleetID = fleetItem.Key;   //outer loop
     foreach(var itm in fleetItem)
     {             
         var groupId = itm.FleetID; // inner loop
     }
}
```

If you are performing the group based on more than one column means you can access them with respect to key, Consider that the grouping is like the folling:

```
var groupedCartItems = cart.CartItems.OrderBy(x => x.FleetID)
                           .GroupBy(x => new { x.FleetID,x.FleetName});
```

Then you can access them like the following:

```
foreach (var fleetItem in groupedCartItems)
{
     var currentFleetID = fleetItem.Key.FleetID;   
     var currentFleetName = fleetItem.Key.FleetName;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, grouping on multiple columns was going to be my next question! Thanks for going above and beyond my original question, appreciated

Answer (score 1):

When you use `GroupBy` you get a collection of `IGrouping` objects, each has a `Key` property, which is what you want, and it can also be iterated using a `foreach` loop to get the items in the group. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343251(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var groupedCartItems = cart.CartItems.OrderBy(x => x.FleetID)
           .GroupBy(x => x.FleetID);

    foreach (var group in groupedCartItems)
    {

        var currentFleetID = group.Key;   ////////

        foreach(var itm in group)
        {

        }
    }
```